# why does scipy clustering not work?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

ImportError: cannot import name _hierarchy

I have updated all the related packages using pip. There were no errors with updating pandas, numpy, scipy and scikit-learn. Still I keep getting this wierd error on executing this command

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq
```

I am using 0.15 version. Really stuck here :(

Comment: Can you reinstall `scipy` and save the installation log? The error message might be related to a failure when building the extension modules.

Comment: actually reinstalling scipy worked! thanks